# Spring boot is failed to start with Java 14

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-module

I was trying to build a sample java 14 program in spring boot, it was building successfully but deployment is failing. I'm using H2 database to store the details, the entity bean is not loading from different java module.

Please find the code base here https://github.com/rjvharidas/spring-boot-java14-module

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'movieController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Dell/My%20Workspace/spring-boot-java14-module/api/target/api-
1.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/rjv/bootcamp/javamodules/api/controller/MovieController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframe
work.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'movieService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Dell/My%20Workspace/spring-boot-java14-module/api/target/api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.
jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/rjv/bootcamp/javamodules/service/service/MovieService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springfram
ework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'movieRepository' defined in com.rjv.bootcamp.javamodules.service.repository.MovieRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared o
n ServiceConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.rjv.bootcamp.javamodules.domain.Movie
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Not a managed type` exception is being thrown when the entity class is not in the package, which is under `@EntityScan`

As I see in your code, you have imported the [ServiceConfiguration](https://github.com/rjvharidas/spring-boot-java14-module/blob/ab09f595decd5be440c83805ecfbb73ea0ec9ade/service/src/main/java/com/rjv/bootcamp/javamodules/service/configuration/ServiceConfiguration.java), which has

```
@EntityScan("com.rjv.bootcamp.javamodules.domain.*")
```

The problem is that the package specifieed in wrong format, ending with `.*`.
Probably, you should replace it with

```
@EntityScan("com.rjv.bootcamp.javamodules.domain")
```